# Android studio Gradle is offline

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an error that **the Gradle is offline**.
Now when I connect it to the *wifi* it shows that pic for a 3 to four hours ago.

[image]

Comment: hie Zaid! can you please tell which OS you are using so I could tell you some steps to do about this issue! and also the version of android studio you are having!

Comment: Have you tried open `Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle` and untick `Offline work` and resync Gradle again?

Comment: I download the new version of the android studio last week.

Comment: Windows  os that I use recently

Comment: @ZaidKhalid look at this [URL](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build)

Comment: @ZaidKhalid did you try Bach Vu  commented solution?  that seems to be a fare try to work along

Comment: Yeah, I try it a couple of time but the error is remain's same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **From what I am seeing this seems like the issue with the gradle**
>   **version of yours.**

Here is what you can do as **first try!**

open Android Studio -> settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle and untick Offline work and resync Gradle again

**Here is what you can do as second try!**
totally **no Harm will happen following the steps**

1:  go to file menu and close project

2:  close all instances of android studio

3:  then go to . C:\users\YOUR_USER_NAME\

4:  you will see property files like .  .gradle, .androidStudio3.3

> deleting that old .gradle file will delete all the gradle cache
>   deleting the .androidStudio3.3 file will delete the basic settings of
>   android studio you did like the custom keymap,plugins,themes etc
>   (optional)

5:   so delete both those files mentioned above

6:  after deleting those just fire up android studio, follow the steps and create a new project

step 6:  creating a new project will make the android studio to download a fresh pack of gradle for your system, and new setting will be made.

6:  when you are able to build the application then open your old project and see if the old error persists